# Heroku: Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: heroku

My blog runs on Ghost and is hosted at Heroku. It worked fine for a couple of weeks, but now, without making any changes it crashed. The error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

But my configuration file is the same as always:

```
production: {
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: process.env.PORT
    }
}
```

Even tried rebooting the dyno and deployed a new version of my blog, but with no luck. Still the same error.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. Heroku wasn't the problem. My database is stored on another server, which probably was hacked. The hosting company detected what appears to be a large flood of traffic from one or more of my servers, that is disrupting the normal traffic flow for other users.
To prevent this traffic from causing further disruption, they had disabled the networking interface on the server or servers involved.

So that was the problem. My Heroku app wasn't able to connect to my database and so the port binding failed.